# Is there a program that automatically tiles all (new) windows?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I'm doing a research on different ways to manage windows on a computer and for that reason I'm searching for a program that automatically tiles all opened Windows including new ones.

I know that there are some programs that use certain Shortcuts to tile all Windows but I don't know if one of them can be configured to do that automatically, so that there are basically no overlapping windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether there are ways to automatically tile all open windows, but both BetterTouchToool (blog.boastr.net, free) or BetterSnapTool (https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) let you organize windows.

I'm not familiar with BetterSnapTool, but with BetterTouchTool you can configure your own actions, so you might be able to get what you want by using a series of built-in actions.